# Boostrap 4 Carousel Image not displaying properly

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a bootstrap 4 carousel and i have added 3 images inside them.
Also i want them as a full screen carousel, where the height of the carousel is the height of the device and it works properly.
But the problem is the image's width, the width seems responsive and stays inside the carousel wrapper but the image is not properly displayed. The image seems cropped and the full image is not properly displayed.
When viewed in normal mode the carousel works properly but when viewed in mobile view the carousel images seems cropped. Here is my code

````
 <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <style>

.full-screen {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <!-- Indicators -->
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            </ol>
                            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/banner-1.png"
                                 data-color="lightblue" alt="First Image">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/banner-2.png" data-color="firebrick" alt="Second Image">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/banner-3.png" data-color="violet" alt="Third Image">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Controls -->
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                          </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                          </a>
                          </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
var $item = $('.carousel-item'); 
var $wHeight = $(window).height();
$item.eq(0).addClass('active');
$item.height($wHeight); 

$item.addClass('full-screen');


$('.carousel img').each(function() {
  var $src = $(this).attr('src');
  var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
  $(this).parent().css({
    'background-image' : 'url(' + $src + ')',
    'background-color' : $color
  });
  $(this).remove();
});

$(window).on('resize', function (){
  $wHeight = $(window).height();
  $item.height($wHeight);
});

$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 1000,
  pause: "false"
});
    </script>
```
````

Here is some sample output snapshots:
Normal View
[image]
Responsive View
[image]

Comment: Your last 3 `scripts` (popper, jquery, js) should really go right above `</body>` after all the other content, per Bootstrap.

Comment: @JeffBerlin i have changed as you mentioned but that doesn't resolve my issue. Still its the same problem. Can you tell where the issue is? Would it be anything with file's original height and width? Because when i ran the original example, the images in that were displayed properly both it in normal/responsive view.

Comment: Yeah, that was more for just fixing where it was supposed to be. I'm still working on trying to figure out your issue

Comment: I suspect the background-size of fullscreen is where your solution lies. Try writing a rule for mobile screens and try a different background-size like 'contain'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a mobile query to set the background size of the image to "contain", rather than "cover" on small screens.

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .full-screen {
      background-size: contain;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `background-size: cover;` in the `.full-screen` CSS and switching it to `background-size: contain;` appeared to fix it on my end. Obviously, you can remove it and the image will be smaller/original size.

```js
var $item = $('.carousel-item'); 
var $wHeight = $(window).height();
$item.eq(0).addClass('active');
$item.height($wHeight); 

$item.addClass('full-screen');


$('.carousel img').each(function() {
  var $src = $(this).attr('src');
  var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
  $(this).parent().css({
    'background-image' : 'url(' + $src + ')',
    'background-color' : $color
  });
  $(this).remove();
});

$(window).on('resize', function (){
  $wHeight = $(window).height();
  $item.height($wHeight);
});

$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 1000,
  pause: "false"
});
```

```css
.full-screen {
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://www.drupal.org/files/drupal-wordmark.svg"
         data-color="lightblue" alt="First Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" data-color="firebrick" alt="Second Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="images/banner-3.png" data-color="violet" alt="Third Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Popper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```